# Shell access for a KVM VM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, shell, openvz, proxmox

I would like to access my KVM VM with a shell.
I created it via proxmox 2.3, Ubuntu 12.04 is installed on it via an official template.
I would like to find the same command as

```
vzctl enter <VM_id>
```

for OpenVZ containers.

I didn't find anything on the proxmox [qm's Wiki](http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Manual:_qm).
Is there anything similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't for KVM guests according to [Proxmox](http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/11783-Access-a-VM-directly-from-Host-Node-Shell?s=8b0462a8da24eef65650a0ec360dbad5&p=64288#post64288).

Comment: So, how do you install stuff on your VM if it's linux distribution ?

Comment: If you need some initial manual setup to get networking working, Libvirt exposes the VM's console over VNC. After that, use SSH.

Comment: libvirt can also provide direct serial console access without ssh or networking

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with proxmox, since it doesn't implement all of KVM's potential. On normal KVM setups with libvirt or other management systems, like oVirt, this is possible using a serial console to the VM.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using virtual terminals for KVM VM.

You need (keep in mind all my examples for Debian 6/7):

1. Run Linux kernel inside KVM VM with kernel param: console=tty0.
   it can be done editing /etc/default/grub : `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet console=tty0"`
2. Add to KVM VM file /etc/inittab this line:`T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -l /usr/local/bin/autologin -n -L ttyS0 115200 vt102`
3. Create file /usr/local/bin/autologin with following content: `#!/bin/sh
   exec /bin/login -f root`
4. reboot the VM
5. Use virsh console kvm_vm_name and work with it like vzctl enter $CTID

If you need any help please comment here :)